# Up Button On V Scrollbar In a TEXTAREA, Inexplicably Greyed Out

Tags: css

Further info : the button is actually only greying out when I go to use it: on mouse~over it
fades, becomes inactive.

I have swapped the CSS Declaration responsible, to use on another TextArea in a different website, and it is happy there, behaves as expected.  However, taking a working CSS declaration from outside, and swapping it into the CSS for the Textarea I am having difficulty with, find that the problem persists.  So I conclude it is very unlikely the CSS is at fault; at least as far as the textarea.

What area of code should I examine next to try to pin this down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is strange to me, but the error was related to z-index.

The problem was the z-index applying to the DIV containing the problematic textarea,
was higher than that for the textarea itself.  So: some way, the up button was not displaying or behaving rather, properly.

The moment I raised the z-index of the Textarea, to a value higher than the containing div, the problem went away.

Anybody stumbling on this question, who may know why just one element was affected, feel free to add a comment, some insight would doubtless be more valueable, but for now, I stumbled on the  (a)  solution.